# How do I display a value that changing every second without doing a page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page that displays a value which changes every second. Much like an example where time would be displayed and the time runs automatically.

For example, I have a method:

```
private void GetMethod()
{
    lblValue.Text = Convert.ToString(value1);
}
```

I need that value to change when it changes on the database, which is in intervals of seconds.

Comment: You could try SignalR, with which it is possible to trigger a client update from the server.

Comment: the simplest and easy solution is a timer.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I use updatePanel in asp.net without refreshing all page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929644/how-do-i-use-updatepanel-in-asp-net-without-refreshing-all-page)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575836/label-text-refresh-every-second ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040828/how-can-i-change-the-text-of-a-texbox-in-every-second ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880306/how-to-refresh-the-asp-net-label-every-second-automatically-using-java-script-in ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740950/how-to-update-every-second-from-db

Answer (score 1):

The right answer depends on what it is that's changing. You say 'constantly', I would *assume* you mean when some 'state' changes on the server. In which case, the SignalR suggestion is spot on since it will take care of most of the other methods that would be suggested to you implicitly (polling, sockets connection etc.).

But - if you mean 'constantly' as in every 1 second something changes regardless of what's happened on the server - a 'push' implementation would be excessive. Have the client do something regularly with `setInterval()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to look into [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) It lets you update data in real-time fashion.